# Julia + Centos - Arpack cannot be built

Tags: centos, julia

I installed julia (v1.1.1) via as stated in [platform specific instructions(https://julialang.org/downloads/platform.html) on my CentOS machine using yum and epel.

Julia works fine, but when precompiling packages (`using DataFrames` for example), I get

```
[ Info: Precompiling GLM [38e38edf-8417-5370-95a0-9cbb8c7f171a]
ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.build("Arpack").
Currently, the build command might fail when Julia has been built from source
and the recommendation is to use the official binaries from julialang.org.
For more info see https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5.
```

I don't know enough about compilations, building from source, etc. to solve this. I guess it would work fine if I just download Julia from the main page and use it from within that folder. But I would prefer using it via package manager to automatically receive updates.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is expected since Arpack.jl expects OpenBLAS to be called libopenblas64_.so.0, while in Fedora/CentOS it is libopenblasp64_.so.0. You can work around the problem using `sudo ln -s /lib64/libopenblas64p_.so.0 ~/.julia/packages/Arpack/*/deps/lib/libopenblas64_.so.0`. I'll try to find a solution with Arpack.jl developers.

Comment: I've included a fix with the Julia 1.2 package I just pushed to the Copr. Please let me know if you still experience problems with that version. The solution I found was to pass `LIBBLASNAME=libopenblas64_` when building Julia, but create symlink from /lib64/julia/libopenblas64_.so to /lib64/libopenblasp64_.so so that the threaded OpenBLAS is used.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually solved this via help of the original julialang page. For some reason, `Arpack` can't be built if you install julia via `# yum install julia` (with epel enabled). `Pkg.build("Arpack")` fails.

If you download julia from the official page and add it to path, it still throws the same error message. If you however start up julia and run `Pkg.build("Arpack")` beforehand, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that @MilanBouchet-Valat solution works. Here is some details for Debian distribution.

I have installed Julia using Debian 4.19.37-5 package manager (synaptic for instance). I have

```
julia> versioninfo()
```

prints

```
Julia Version 1.0.4
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 v3 @ 1.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

- **The symptoms**

Under Julia I got the "expected" error when trying to install the **Arpack** package:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Arpack
```

prints

```
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [7d9fca2a] + Arpack v0.3.1
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]
```

then

```
julia> using Arpack
```

prints

```
[ Info: Precompiling Arpack [7d9fca2a-8960-54d3-9f78-7d1dccf2cb97]
ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running 
Pkg.build("Arpack").

Currently, the build command might fail when Julia has been built from source
and the recommendation is to use the official binaries from julialang.org.
For more info see https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5.

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /home/picaud/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/src/Arpack.jl:19
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [5] top-level scope at none:2
 [6] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [7] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:393
 [8] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /home/picaud/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/src/Arpack.jl:16
ERROR: Failed to precompile Arpack [7d9fca2a-8960-54d3-9f78-7d1dccf2cb97] to /home/picaud/.julia/compiled/v1.0/Arpack/X5VZL.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
```

however

```
 pkg> build Arpack
```

prints

```
  Building Arpack → `~/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `Arpack`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: LibraryProduct(nothing, ["libarpack"], :libarpack, "Prefix(/home/picaud/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/deps/usr)") is not satisfied, cannot generate deps.jl!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] #write_deps_file#152(::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at /home/picaud/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/TcAwt/src/Products.jl:414
│  [3] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#kw##write_deps_file")))(::NamedTuple{(:verbose,),Tuple{Bool}}, ::typeof(write_deps_file), ::String, ::Array{LibraryProduct,1}) at ./none:0
│  [4] top-level scope at none:0
│  [5] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [8] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [9] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/picaud/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/deps/build.jl:74
└ @ Pkg.Operations /build/julia-gbfU8y/julia-1.0.4+dfsg/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1096
```

- **The diagnostic**

You can check that this is a dependance problem with:

```
ldd ~/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/deps/usr/lib/libarpack.so
```

prints

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc179a1000)
    libopenblas64_.so.0 => not found            <----
    libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007feea073d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feea05ba000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007feea05a0000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007feea0557000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feea0396000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feea0c67000)
```

Debian distro:

```
find /usr/lib/ -name libopenblas\*
```

prints

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.3.6.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas64_.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/libopenblas.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.3.6.so
```

- **The "fix"**

With root privileges (su) create a symbolic links

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas64_.so.0
```

Now it works

```
pkg> build Arpack
Building Arpack → `~/.julia/packages/Arpack/cu5By/deps/build.log`
```

then

```
using Arpack
[ Info: Precompiling Arpack [7d9fca2a-8960-54d3-9f78-7d1dccf2cb97]
```

are OK